# Javascript getDate as -> Sun Jan 15 2017 04:05:51pm GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)

Tags: javascript

Simple,

```
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=Date();
```

Output:
**Sun Jan 15 2017 16:05:51 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)**

Output preferred:
**Sunday, 1/01/2017, 1:11:11 PM · GMT-0500 (EST)**

If anyone knows how that could be done and incorporated into this script here, that would be cool.

```
new Date(abbr.dataset.utime * 1000).toLocaleString() + '</span>');
```

Basically I want the first digit to always be a single digit, and the days of the month to always be two digits. Same for the clock. 1:01:01 PM but NOT 01:01:01 PM

Much easier way is to use toLocaleDateString

```
var options = { weekday: 'long', year: 'numeric', month: 'numeric', day: '2-digit' }; 

new Date(abbr.dataset.utime * 1000).toLocaleDateString('en-US', options) + '</span>');
```

Comment: Will require a bunch of string parsing, or simplest is probably to use a library like `moment.js`. This isn't a code writing service

Comment: Use a library to format js time. There are multiple around, re-implementing it by hand is going to be unpleasant

Comment: I know it's not a code writing service, but as I'm learning Javascript, I can't believe how complicated it is just to output a date. O_o

Comment: @JZersche Dates are one of the hardest parts of programming :)

Comment: I guess that explains it. I remember it being easier in PHP, haha.

Answer (score 0):

You'll find the amount of headache necessary to solve this particular problem is counter productive to the amount of time spent learning how to use a thoroughly tested library written by professional keepers of time.

When you do solve this problem in vanilla javascript, compare it to this one-liner written in [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/):

```js
console.log(moment(new Date()).format('dddd, M/DD/YYYY, h:mm:ss A · [GMT]ZZ'));
```

```html
<script src="http://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.min.js"></script>
```

For that last part about including the timezone (EST), you need to use the [Moment Timezone](http://momentjs.com/timezone/) plugin.

Comment: Cool. Thanks! Brother!